# Code behind not seeing aspx div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add text to a div in an asp.net webforms page:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
</div>
```

and c#:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label test = new Label();
        test.Text = "test";
        div1.Controls.Add(test);
    }
```

However I am getting an error:

[image]

I dont understand as I have not seen this behavior before.

Comment: Make sure you have rebuild your project

Comment: @CodeNotFound Yes, I tried that.

Comment: Did you  happen to add the div while you were in the middle of a debug run? Try this: cut the div from the markup, rebuild, and paste it back, and make sure VS is not debugging. I bet it's missing from the designer file.

Comment: There actually is no designer file.

Comment: For this page only or for any existing/new page?

Comment: @David: Which version of ASP.NET? I would expect a `yourpage.aspx.designer.cs` file with a `protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div1;` line in it. That's what your code-behind would be looking for, anyway.

Comment: I did New project > ASP.NET Web App > ASP.NET 4.5.2 Empty Template and generated the aspx and aspx.cs page myself. Perhaps that is the issue. How do I generate a designer?

Comment: Do you have the "Show all files" option toggled? (i.e., in the Solution Explorer, can you expand the .aspx file like you would a folder?) Highlight your project, on the toolbar at the top of the Solution Explorer there's a little multi-icon thing that toggles this option. Toggle it on, then you should be able to open the designer file. Or, skip all this, and just recreate the div by cutting and pasting it back.

Comment: After creating the designer file  and re-pasting like you said it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can cause this issue is not having:

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
```

in the .cs file